# R: creating associations and group variable

Tags: r, comparison

I have two categorical variables: Size 1 (participant) and Size 2 (stimulus), each with 3 levels (small, medium, large). I would like to associate the size of the participants with the size of stimulus and run a comparative analysis. For example, comparing SS with SM and SL, to have a look if participants of Size S reacted more to the same size, to medium or large.
Also, do you think would it be also possible to assign the combinations to specific groups to do a comparison on a group size level?

Currently it looks like this:

```
| Size1 | Size2 |
|-------|-------|
| S     | S     |
| M     | M     |
| L     | L     |
| S     | M     |
| M     | L     |
| S     | L     |
| M     | S     |
| L     | S     |
| L     | M     |
```

this is how it should look:

```
| Size1 | Size2 | Combination | Group |
|-------|-------|-------------|-------|
| S     | S     | SS          | 1     |
| M     | M     | MM          | 1     |
| L     | L     | LL          | 1     |
| S     | M     | SM          | 2     |
| M     | L     | ML          | 2     |
| S     | L     | SL          | 2     |
| M     | S     | MS          | 3     |
| L     | S     | LS          | 3     |
| L     | M     | LM          | 3     |
```

I would be very grateful for every hint!

Thanks

Comment: This question is off-topic on stack overflow, because it doesn't involve programming (even though you tagged 'R'). Your question is asking for a statistical procedure. Try asking it at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have preconceived ideas and you want to view the possible relations between the categories I would recommend you to do a correspondence analysis. In the link below you have an introduction to this analysis in R.

https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/ca.html

Eitherway , you have several analysis that you can perform for looking for relations between the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the following example:

```
> my_data <- ToothGrowth
> res_aov <- aov(len ~ supp + dose + supp:dose, data = my_data)
> res_hsd <- TukeyHSD(res.aov, which = "supp:dose")

> res_hsd
Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = len ~ supp + dose + supp:dose, data = my_data)

$`supp:dose`
               diff        lwr        upr     p adj
VC:0.5-OJ:0.5 -5.25 -10.048124 -0.4518762 0.0242521
OJ:1-OJ:0.5    9.47   4.671876 14.2681238 0.0000046
VC:1-OJ:0.5    3.54  -1.258124  8.3381238 0.2640208
OJ:2-OJ:0.5   12.83   8.031876 17.6281238 0.0000000
VC:2-OJ:0.5   12.91   8.111876 17.7081238 0.0000000
OJ:1-VC:0.5   14.72   9.921876 19.5181238 0.0000000
VC:1-VC:0.5    8.79   3.991876 13.5881238 0.0000210
OJ:2-VC:0.5   18.08  13.281876 22.8781238 0.0000000
VC:2-VC:0.5   18.16  13.361876 22.9581238 0.0000000
VC:1-OJ:1     -5.93 -10.728124 -1.1318762 0.0073930
OJ:2-OJ:1      3.36  -1.438124  8.1581238 0.3187361
VC:2-OJ:1      3.44  -1.358124  8.2381238 0.2936430
OJ:2-VC:1      9.29   4.491876 14.0881238 0.0000069
VC:2-VC:1      9.37   4.571876 14.1681238 0.0000058
VC:2-OJ:2      0.08  -4.718124  4.8781238 1.0000000
```

NOTE: Be sure that your categories are `factor` in your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I assume have more to data than shown here, particularly measure of reaction.

**1. Comparing SS with SM and SL**

I would suggest using one-way ANOVA

```
size_aov <- aov(var_reaction ~ Combination, data = df[Size1=="S",])
```

**2. Do you think would it be also possible to assign the combinations to specific groups to do a comparison on a group size level?**

I am going by suggested data and please check that both the size variables are ordered.

```
df$group[df$Size1 == df$Size2] <- 1
df$group[as.numeric(df$Size1) < as.numeric(df$Size2)] <- 2
df$group[as.numeric(df$Size1) > as.numeric(df$Size2)] <- 3
```